# How do you generate a TOC (Table Of Contents) in markdown-mode?

Tags: markdown, markdown-mode

The function needs to get at least the levels two (`## title`) and three (`### title`) titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
(defun px/markdown-toc ()
  "Extract level 2 and 3 headings from the current Markdown buffer.
   The generated and indented TOC will be inserted at point."
  (interactive)
  (let (toc-list markdown-toc)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward "^\\(##+\\)\\s-+\\(.*\\)" nil t)
        (let* ((level (length (match-string 1)))
               (heading-text (match-string 2))
               (heading-id (downcase (replace-regexp-in-string "[[:space:]]+" "-" heading-text))))
          (push (cons level (cons heading-text heading-id)) toc-list))))
    (setq toc-list (reverse toc-list))
    (dolist (item toc-list)
      (let* ((level (car item))
             (heading-text (cadr item))
             (heading-id (cddr item))
             (indentation (make-string (* 2 (1- level)) ?\ ))
             (line (format "- [%s](#%s)\n" heading-text heading-id)))
        (setq markdown-toc (concat markdown-toc (concat indentation line)))))
    (insert markdown-toc)))
```

Comment: If this works and you're happy with it, please don't forget to mark it as accepted.